# What is the difference between "mère" and "mère de famille"?

Tags: sens, expressions, noms, différence

What is the difference between "mère" and "mère de famille"?  Are they interchangeable?

Answer (score 12):

`Mère` is basically `mother`.

`Mère de famille` highlights the role of a mother inside a family and as such, is more for describing your situation, like during an interview or a date. You can think of it like you would say in English `mother of two` (or any number of children).

So they are not always interchangeable, you couldn't replace `mère` by `mère de famille` in such a case (try replacing the English version by `mother of two`):

> Ma mère est géniale = My mother is great

But:

> Je m'appelle Sonia, j'ai 38 ans, je suis infirmière et mère de famille / mère de deux enfants = My name is Sonia, I'm 38 years old, I'm a nurse and mother of two

Now in English you can often use "mother" alone for a description, like `Do you remember her? She's a mother now!`, but in French it would sound strange, at least for me, and I would say `Tu te souviens d'elle ? Maintenant elle est mère de famille !` (or more naturally `Maintenant elle a des enfants !`).

Some translations suggest `housewife` but it would rather be `femme au foyer`, that doesn't even imply you have children. There is `mère au foyer` too, but you can be a `mère de famille` and have a job, where a `mère au foyer` doesn't have a paid job (it's a housewife with children... a *"housemother"*).

Answer (score 6):

They *can* be interchangeable but are not so to a great extent.

- C'est une mère, elle ne peut pas rester trop longtemps sans savoir comment va son fils.
  *Here you insist on the parental relation and it is not as appropriate to add "de famille".*
- C'est une mère de famille, elle n'a pas tant de temps à elle, il vaut mieux demander à quelqu'un qui pourra se consacrer à cette tâche plus librement.
  *In this example you insist rather on the charge of having to take care of one or more children. You might dispense with the complement but it is better not to.*

You can say then that when using just "mère" you limit the scope of the discourse to the domain of the parental relation, of affection; when adding the complement that entails that your discourse is rather situated on the level of responsability.

In the example "La voiture avait à son bord une mère de famille et sa fille." it is the woman's responsability that is to be considered rather, but you could say just "mère".

In the following examples you might say either.

- Une mère (de famille) et sa fille were having their meal at one of the front tables.
  Here you can choose the aspect you want, it doesn't matter so much, but nevertheless the idea will conferred by whichever you choose is still valid.*

Here is another example in which both are possible.

- Elle est devenue mère (de famille) il n'y a pas très longtemps.

Answer (score 3):

***Mère*** and ***mère de famille*** are not in a situation to be interchangeable because they are not really used in the same circumstances.

***Mère de famille*** is an administrative way to define a status, often used in statistics, reports, news, etc. It is rarely used in the conversation. It might be used to disambiguate *les mères* with *les maires* (The mayors).

***Mère*** is a neutral way to refer to woman who gave birth to one or more children. It is often used to define the relationship (***ma*** mère, **sa** mère, la mère **de** xxx, *les mères et leurs filles* but never *ma/sa/ta/leur mère de famille*). *Mère* is also used in administrative forms along with *père*.

***Maman*** was missing from your list. It is an affective way to refer to a mother and to call yours or someone's mother (*Maman*, *sa maman*, *la maman de xxx*, *les mamans et les papas*...).

LPH suggested a translation for "she's a mother now!" that avoids *mère*. There is actually a way to keep the concept by using *maman*:

> *C'est une maman maintenant !*

Answer (score 1):

Selon https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/m%C3%A8re_de_famille (NB : Après la réponse le lemme wiki a été modifié) :

> mère de famille \mɛʁ də fa.mij\ féminin (pour un homme on dit : père
> de famille)
>
> *Femme mariée qui a des enfants* (**le lemme maintenant ne parle pas de "mariée**).
>
> Le lendemain, de bon matin, Mme
> Étienne était sur pied. En vraie mère de famille, elle visita les deux
> paquets de linge et d’habits que les deux voyageurs portaient sur
> l’épaule, et elle mit de bonnes pièces aux pantalons ou aux blouses
> qui en avaient besoin. — (G. Bruno, Le Tour de la France par deux
> enfants, Chapitre IV, 1904)

Voici la définition de Littré

> Mère de famille, femme mariée qui a des enfants. La véritable mère de
> famille, loin d'être une femme du monde, n'est guère moins recluse
> dans sa maison que la religieuse dans son cloître, Rousseau, Ém. V. Y
> a-t-il au monde un spectacle aussi touchant, aussi respectable, que
> celui d'une mère de famille entourée de ses enfants, réglant les
> travaux de ses domestiques, procurant à son mari une vie heureuse, et
> gouvernant sagement la maison ? Rousseau, Lett. à d'Alemb

Comme @LPH le remarque :

> Il semble que la définition trouvée ne soit pas une erreur ; voilà ce
> que donne le TLFi : Mère de famille. Femme mariée s'occupant de la
> maison et des enfants. . Apparemment il existe ou a existé jusqu'à il
> n'y a pas très longtemps deux courants d'idée et leur usage.

Voir aussi

https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/merdeuf

**EDIT**

Je pose la question à ma collègue professeure de français, allemand et anglais. Elle m'a dit qu'elle trouve "mère de famille" plutôt un pléonasme de nos jours.

Comment: I am surprised the definition links the concept of "mère de famille" to being married. I have the feeling that this matched the "traditional" idea of a mother, where parents necessarily had to be married to have children. Nowadays, this looks outdated by the social evolution of marriage: a *mère de famille* can be described as such even if her couple is not married, or even if she is a single mother.

Comment: @Greg I believe it's always been that way, a divorced lady with children has never been denied the name of "mère de famille".

Comment: I appreciate the answer but I agree with the comments: someone needs to edit that wiki, a single parent + their kid(s) does constitute a family.

Comment: I edited the wiki.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt One should also edit and this: https://www.linternaute.fr/dictionnaire/fr/definition/mere-de-famille/

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt By the way:-)! Voici une ancienne source de la mère de la famille: https://books.google.es/books?id=sLTL8HhCW-wC&pg=PA363&lpg=PA363&dq=%22mere+de+famille%22++definition&source=bl&ots=1Sn3rGI4uW&sig=ACfU3U2U7Wm8HHfQHjaIFJUcI0B0Xh46EA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjZ0ZfNhfflAhUHtRoKHWY6D3wQ6AEwCnoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22mere%20de%20famille%22%20%20definition&f=false

Comment: Il semble que la définition que vous avez trouvée ne soit pas une erreur ; voilà ce que donne le TLFi : Mère de famille. Femme mariée s'occupant de la maison et des enfants. . Apparemment il existe ou a existé jusqu'à il n'y a pas très longtemps deux courants d'idée et leur usage.

Comment: @LPH J'ai rajouté votre commentaire. Merci !